# Save input to a file

Tags: java, file, io, command

I'm building a command shell, and in this command shell I want to save every command i write to a file.

I read commands Like this:

```
    BufferedReader console = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    commandLine = console.readLine();
```

I write to file like this:

```
    public static void fileWriter(String e){
    try{
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("errorLog.txt"));
            bw.write(e);
            bw.flush();
            bw.close();
    }
    catch(IOException ex){
        System.out.println(ex);
    }        
}
```

The problem is, every command overwrites the last one, so I cant save every command written during the command shells session. What I need is a list of all commands I wrote.

I've been googleing this for about 2 hours and I cant find anything. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("errorLog.txt",true));
```

The `true` tells the FileWriter to append the data and not overwrite. See the documentation.

```
public FileWriter(String fileName,boolean append) throws IOException

Constructs a FileWriter object given a file name with a boolean 
indicating whether or not to append the data written.
```

Comment: something like this I was looking for, but this just gives me an error `no suitable constructor found` EDIT: Still getting used to coding in notepad :P this kind of works, I want the file to reset when I start the command shell again

Comment: Can you please check whether your syntax matches exactly how I have it above here?

Comment: I edited right before you write this ^^ my syntax was wrong, I was missing a ")"

Comment: Could you tell me how to reset the file at startup? Forgot to write this in my question

Comment: For that you will need to keep a static boolean variable and in your fileWriter() function, simply do a check whether it is the first time you are writing. If yes, set the append flag to false. If no, set it to true.

Comment: Ah, that is better then what I did, I just deleted the file and created a now one ^^

Answer (score 0):

I'd keep every command in a global array and add every new command to it, then write every value in the array to your file.
Or read your file, add your new value, and write everything to the file again

Comment: Ye, thought about that, but thought there might be a better way. But to tired to care now, will try this :)